# jQuery Click - POST/GET return success' return value

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, get, click

[name=AddClientSubmit] ... is the "submit" button on a form.

The $.POST sends the forms data and the post script returns a json response with an error message in it.

If there is no error message I want to return the click function as true so the form is submitted and false if there is an error.

**Problem with my script below is javascript doesn't wait for the $.POST to fully finish and the submitForm value is never set so the form automatically is submitted.**

```
 $('[name="addClientSubmit"]').click(function() {
    var submitForm = false;
    var buttonObj = $(this);
    buttonObj.hide();

    $.post(
        '/jquery/scripts/contacts_clientAddEdit.php',
        $('#addClientForm').serialize(),
        function(json) {
            if(json.error == '') {
                submitForm = 'yes';
            } else {
                jAlert(json.error, 'Error', function() {
                    buttonObj.show();   
                });
                submitForm = 'no';  
            }
        },
        'json'
        );

        if(submitForm == 'yes') { return true; }
        if(submitForm == 'no') { return false; }
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the $.post method is asynchronous so it will return before the submission is complete. There is a way to turn this off but it causes the browser to hang and sometimes behave to the user as if it has crashed.

Instead of creating two separate posts, one for this AJAX functionality and one for the form why not combine them? This will both resolve your issue and result in a quicker response time for the user.

Comment: Unfortunately the way things are setup this "new client" form is used in several different admin sections. Each admin section redirects the user to a different page after form has been submit.  So basically this AJAX call is just to validate the form via a POST. I wish there was another work around. I guess I can pass in the admin section type and just return the redirection URL which the POST success function can handle.

Comment: "I guess I can pass in the admin section type and just return the redirection URL which the POST success function can handle." I take by the "I guess" you feel this may be something of a hack but I assure you it's not. A server side redirect still returns the URL to the client it's just automatically handled by the browser. There's nothing fundamentally wrong with allowing this mechanism to be handled by javascript.

Comment: Thanks for you help!  I don't really see it as a hack, I just have been working on this project for so long that I wish my first thought process was the correct answer because I am not in the mood to change/re-code things.

Comment: I understand the sentiment but I can assure you that if you implement methods that utilize AJAX methodologies to it's full potential you'll feel an immense amount of satisfaction.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by modifying the code in this way:

```
$('[name="addClientSubmit"]').click(function() {
var submitForm = false;
var buttonObj = $(this);
buttonObj.hide();

$.post(
    '/jquery/scripts/contacts_clientAddEdit.php',
    $('#addClientForm').serialize(),
    function(json) {
        if(json.error == '') {
            submitForm = 'yes';
            return true;
        } else {
            jAlert(json.error, 'Error', function() {
                buttonObj.show();   
            });
            submitForm = 'no';  
            return false;
        }
    },
    'json'
    );

});
```

Comment: That method doesn't work because the return true or return false doesn't carry outside of the $.POST success function.

Comment: You can use stop() and submit() functions to make it work in a different way. For example do $('#addClientForm').submit() inside the success function.